# Preprocessing data\[Ellipsis]. or Preprocessing data..... error in ParallelTable in Mathematica

Tags: parallelization, machine-learning

I am working on Machine Learning. My purpose in the code is to repeat calculation a few times and average the results. While using Table command, following message pops up for ClassifiersMeasurements and continues.
[image: Preprocessing data]

If I use ParallelTable to repeat simultaneously since they  are independent, kernel messages fill the notebook and gets stuck at some point.

Here is the screencast:

[image: kernel messages]

I have tried Quite, Off, Turning off Dynamic Updates. Nothing worked so far.

Your help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

EDIT....
I just add the example to the same question.

The code works fine as following.

```
data = Table[
   Table[Random[], {j, 30}] -> RandomChoice[{0, 1}], {i, 60000}];
measurement = Table[
   dataTran = RandomSample[data, 0.1*Length@data];
   dataTest = Complement[data, dataTran];
   c = Classify[dataTran, TrainingProgressReporting -> None];
   accuracy = ClassifierMeasurements[c, dataTest, "Accuracy"];
   fScore = ClassifierMeasurements[c, dataTest, "FScore"];
   {accuracy, fScore}, {r, 3}];
measurement
```

However, it gets stuck by ParallelTable:

```
data = Table[
   Table[Random[], {j, 30}] -> RandomChoice[{0, 1}], {i, 60000}];
measurement = ParallelTable[
   dataTran = RandomSample[data, 0.1*Length@data];
   dataTest = Complement[data, dataTran];
   c = Classify[dataTran, TrainingProgressReporting -> None];
   accuracy = ClassifierMeasurements[c, dataTest, "Accuracy"];
   fScore = ClassifierMeasurements[c, dataTest, "FScore"];
   {accuracy, fScore}, {r, 3}];
measurement
```

If you have no Preprocessing data window, you might increase the data size. This size is enough for laptop to generate the error.

Comment: You can wrap the call to ClassifiersMeasurements`` in `Block[{Print, PrintTemporary}, ...]` to prevent it from printing lines like these.

Comment: Thank you, Sjoerd, but it didn't work.

Comment: I would call this a bug, and I suggest you report it to Wolfram.

Comment: @forumcash Could you edit the post with a minimal example of the issue?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, I have added examples. Thank you for spending time.

Comment: @forumcash On a different note: have you seen the resource function [CrossValidateModel](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CrossValidateModel)? It might help you out with what you're trying to do.

Comment: And also: `ClassifierMeasurements[c, dataTest, {"Accuracy", "FScore"}]` is more efficient for computing multiple measurements.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, Thank you for elaborating.
Yes, I am aware cross validation, but that is what I am trying to do it now.
ClassifierMeasurements[c, dataTest, {"Accuracy", "FScore"}] is very a smart coding. I implemented. It was ten lines of code, but now it is 1 line. 

It would great to make these measurements in parallel. I will be happy if you can provide a solution. It does not have to be the same as I did.

Comment: Another question: what version are you on? I just tried a few things in 12.3 and didn't find a way yet to suppress the messages, much to my frustration. You're right; blocking print doesn't seem to work and I'm pretty sure it used to work in the past.

Comment: I use 12.3 and 12.2. Both are not working.

Comment: I would also like this answered.